# FullText in SOLR based on substring of specific field

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search

I am using Apache Solr in a project I am working on.
I have all the setup done and I am also able to perform SOLR queries.
However - I am puzzled by one behavior of SOLR - and even after searching on forums - cannot understand the behavior.

In my solr schema, I have one `field` whose type is `solr.TextField`.
I am trying to do a fullTextSearch over it. The query returns me the results only if I include the wildcard character `*`  both before and after the search keyword. It does not work if I include it only at the end (eg: `searchWord*`)

However, many online forums mention that `*` is not supported at beginning of Search term by solr/lucene.

Please find below the `schema.xml`. Note:  I am using solr v 7.4.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<schema name="blog_schema" version="1.4">

  <types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" />
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" />
    <fieldType name="long" class="org.apache.solr.schema.LongPointField" docValues="true" />
    <fieldType name="date" class="org.apache.solr.schema.DatePointField"  docValues="true" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
  </types>

  <fields>
    <field name="post_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="corpus" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false"  />
    <field name="fullText" type="text" indexed="true" multiValued="true" />
    <copyField source="*"  dest="fullText" />
  </fields>

  <uniqueKey>post_id</uniqueKey>


</schema>
```

You can see that I have defined the `corpus` and the `fullText` fields as having the type `solr.TextField`. Both these fields have lot of textual data.

I intend to do a full text search over the `corpus` or `fullText` fields.
For this purpose I am using the SOLR query as follows:
`corpus:*Thermodynamics*`

The above query uses wildcards and it does work and returns me expected results. But I do not understand if it is the right way to do. Many forums mention that `*` at beginning of search query is not supported.
Another observation is :  if I just use the very first word in the corpus and search for it using `corpus: Thermodynamics*` - it does work. This however does not work for word which appear later in the corpus (i.e all word which are not the first word in the corpus)

I was under the impression that SOLR would understand that whitespace/newline is to be ignored.
So - lets say the corpus has the text: `Physics has a specialization for Thermodynamics and Heat`. Then the SOLR query `corpus: Thermodynamics*` or `corpus: Thermodynamics` should work because already `Thermodynamics` is a word in itself and SOLR would understand to ignore that whitespace should be ignored.
Instead I am required to include wildcard `*` both at beginning and end of search term.

Please help me explain
1. why is this behavior so despite forums claiming that `*` at beginning of search term is not supported by SOLR.
2. whether the way I am doing fullText over the `corpus` field is the right way?

Thanks,
Chetan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things in play here, so let's start with the field type:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" />
```

.. this doesn't really define a useful field type. To do that, you'll want to attach a tokenizer and a couple of filters. The tokenizer splits text into tokens, and tokens are what produces a match. This is called an analysis chain.

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

A Whitespace tokenizer will split "foo bar baz" into three tokens, `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. Any queries will do the same, and match token for token. That's why you'll get a match, even if the search is `bar baz foo` and not the same sequence as earlier. You usually want to attach at least a `LowercaseFilter` as well, so that you get case insensitive search - and any more filters depending on what the use case for your field and domain is. Create multiple fields to perform different matches, and weigh them separately to get the document scoring that makes most sense for your users.

Without this analysis chain, I believe you'll in effect get the same behavior as a string field.

Then wildcards - if a wildcard is present, this whole analysis chain is skipped. That means that using wildcards when searching in text, usually is a bad idea. It won't do what you think it does, unless you're trying to match a single token (since the Tokenizer will be skipped when a wildcard is present). So you'll have to do that with care, and you'll probably end up in "why did this happen" more often than not.

The alternative is to use a NGramFilter, which splits each set of letters in a word ( `foo` becomes `f`, `fo`, `foo`, `o`, `oo` and `o`) into separate tokens. You usually only want to do this when indexing, so use separate analysis chains for your field (you define this by the `type` parameter in the configuration - if no type is given, the same chain will be used for indexing and querying.

The reason for prefix wildcards (`*foo`) being adviced against, is that checking for prefix wildcards is expensive compared to checking for a postfix wildcard (`foo*`). In the postfix case you can just iterate over the index from `foo` and keep going until you hit something that doesn't start with `foo`, while for `*foo` you have to effectively look at all the terms in the index, since there is no sorted order that keeps track of these in reverse.

Enter the [Reverse Wildcard Filter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#reversed-wildcard-filter) - what this filter does is that it, in addition to your regular tokens, also indexes the reverse token (or just the reverse token). The filter is then invoked when querying, and reverses the query token as well - effectively indexing `oof`, and then querying for `oof*` internally instead. That way you get the speed up of keeping the index sorted for that field, and you don't have to look at each token.

> This filter reverses tokens to provide faster leading wildcard and prefix queries. Tokens without wildcards are not reversed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I will work on the analyzer  and the rest of the points mentioned.